# How to dynamically add CSV headers while more lines are added to the files

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

A client is sending me lists of key-value pairs that I need to append to a **CSV file with headers**.

```
lang=java                           lang, version, maven
version=1.8              ----->     java, 1.8, true
maven=true
```

and another input might be:

```
lang=C#                           lang, version, maven
version=7.2              ----->   java, 1.8, true
maven=false                       C#, 7.2, false
```

The number of lists might be several millions, so I need to flush the data to the disk and can't keep it all in memory.

As the list of keys is determined by the client, I though to use the first input from him to determine the headers of the CSV file:

`org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(x, y, z ...)));`

and from that point to append only the values at the relevant columns:

```
csvPrinter.printRecord(xValue, yValue, zValue.....)
```

However, it is a *naughty* client, and sometimes he is sending new key that was never seen before by me:

```
lang=java
meetMeAt=London
version=1.4
maven=false
```

How, at this point, I can add another header to the CSV?

What about first saving all the lists to a csv file **without headers**, accumulate all the headers in program memory and then to create another file with all the headers and copy to it the records from the first file? Is it reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution has a problem that we need to solve:

```
lang=java                           java, 1.8, true
version=1.8              ----->     
maven=true

lang=java                           java, 1.8, true
version=1.8              ----->           ???
gradle=true
```

How do you want to represent that? Add another column? How do you know you need to add another column when you don't know the column headers?

If you can afford to read the input twice, I suggest you collect the headers in the first read, and then re-read with already known column headers and positions.

If you need to only read the input once, your idea can work this way:

- Keep the headers and the respective column positions in memory
- Write the CSV without headers, but put all data in the correct columns

  - Note that column count may grow, with first rows having less columns than the last ones
- When you're done with the original input, re-write the output CSV:

  - Put the headers at first line
  - Add missing columns to all rows that are shorter than the final column count